# Cell click event for unbound columns in datagridview

Tags: c#, forms

I want to display three comboboxz in a single cell of datagridview for a single column say date. I want to represent a list for day, month and year each.

Comment: and the question is... ?

Comment: My guess is you have to create a custom user control, a user control that hosts three different comboboxes..

Comment: What 'datagridview' are you using - standard .Net, DevExpess, or..?

Comment: I believe three controls won't be possible, so you can go for a custom datepickercolumn or custom maskedtextbox column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must implement a custom control for grouping the three comboboxes then implement a custom  grid column style for hosting the control, like described here:

[How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)

(incidentally, the linked tutorial describes how to host a calendar control, which you may want to consider instead of the three comboboxes)